Why is docker not serving my laravel automatically?
So i have a problem ai can't seem to fix nor i can find a solution..
I am making a project using react, sass and laravel with docker and docker won't serve my laravel online.. It keeps infinitely loading and i don't know what to do anymore.
This is my directory tree, i know it's scuffed but it works  :)
my-project/   
├── backend/   
│ └── (Laravel files here)   
├── frontend/   
│ └── (React files here)  
├── docker/   
│ ├── backend/  
│     └── Dockerfile  
│ ├── frontend/   
│     └── Dockerfile   
└── docker-compose.yml  

This is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ../  # Root of the project
      dockerfile: docker/backend/Dockerfile  # Path to the Dockerfile
    image: lerenlerentool-backend
    container_name: lerenlerentool_backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www
    entrypoint: php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ../backend:/var/www  # Maps the backend folder into the container
      - ./backend/php-local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - app-network
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=local
      - APP_DEBUG=true
      - APP_KEY=base64:ertrdSfHv01dD/4R6N6acsRQW+hLn3MTNmk84ypaW4I=
      - DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_DATABASE=lerenlerentool
      - DB_USERNAME=test
      - DB_PASSWORD=1234
    depends_on:
      - db

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/frontend/Dockerfile
    image: lerenlerentool-frontend
    container_name: lerenlerentool_frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    volumes:
      - ../frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: lerenlerentool_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: lerenlerentool
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: lerenlerentool_phpmyadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:

And here is my dockerfile:
# Use a PHP image with FPM support
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Install necessary PHP extensions
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev zip git unzip

# Install Composer (for Laravel dependency management)
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

# Set the working directory to where the Laravel project is
WORKDIR /var/www/backend

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev \
    libonig-dev libzip-dev zip unzip git curl \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql bcmath mbstring

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

# Copy the Laravel project files into the container
COPY backend /var/www/backend  

# Install Laravel dependencies via Composer
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

# Install Node.js and npm (if necessary for any assets)
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_22.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs

# Run Laravel migrations or other setup commands if needed
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000

# Expose the correct port (if needed for API)
EXPOSE 8000

I tried to edit my dockerfile with this:
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000

and my compose with this:
entrypoint: php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0

But i still have to go into the folder where my laravel project is and manually input the serve command into the cmd of that folder for the laravel to work.

"It keeps infinitely loading" is not a sufficient problem description. Exactly what actions do you take and what exactly is the result?

I dont know what you mean bout the what actions i take, but when i try to reach the laravel env on the web the website is infinitely loading until i manually put the command   "php artisan serve" into the cmd of that folder. I'm trying to make the server automatically start with starting the docker image.

I have found the answer! It had something to do with the .env file  from my laravel... The file wasn't correctly configured and i changed the APP_URL to: APP_URL=http://localhost:8000. and now with some time loading the backend loads on my chrome.

The fact that you need to manually run php artisan serve suggests that the entrypoint or CMD in your Docker container isn't properly configured to automatically run the Laravel server.

In your docker-compose.yml, remove the entrypoint field, since you're
already handling that in the Dockerfile.



In your Dockerfile, you've set CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000. You may want to make sure that this command is being executed properly, especially after composer install.



Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. - Please [edit] the answer and provide the code/data/errors as text.

I have tried this, and i get no errors in console anymore or the infinite loading from the web. But now the site is unreachable on 0.0.0.0:8000.
